# Show a translucent/transparent modal view with support for device rotation

Tags: ios, view, orientation, modal-dialog, transparent

I want to show a translucent/transparent modal view that should cover the entire screen except status bar. Also, I shall be having different layouts for portrait and landscape orientation (in that modal view). I have done thorough googling and found some solutions. Below, i am summarizing them as well with their problems:

1. Add a view directly to the window: This works nice, but the problem
   is device rotation. If I go by whatever I have experimented/learnt
   so far, the UIWindow bounds do not change on rotating
   the device. This poses a problem - I can't have my landscape modal
   view unless until I do some sort of transformation on my view -
   something which I am reluctant to. I am also not sure, whether it
   will work, as I may have a webview of 1/3rd of the screen height and
   full device width in portrait (rest area is translucent), and 1/4th of the screen width, full device 
   height (minus status bar) in landscape. I read that window changes the bounds (size and coordinate space orientation as well) of Root View controller's view bounds - can't I ask it to change the bounds of my modal view as well? After all Root controller view is also added to the window as a subview only.
2. Adding the modal view to the root controller
   view: This is working fine for me so far with my custom root
   controller based app. The problem is, I have to write my code as a
   generic module, so that it can be used with different types of
   applications. So, if the application root controller is one of the
   out of the box container root controller ( like
   UINavigationController, UITableViewController, etc ), then, is it
   allowed to add a subview directly to their view ? i.e. is is not against the
   Apple guidelines? While reading documentation, I read somewhere that
   we should not play with standard UI controls, like Buttons.
3. While reading documentation, I also read it somewhere that UIAlertViews are
   shown using another Window. How do we do that? is it normal to add
   another window to the app? If things are as per the Apple
   guidelines, I can try this approach  - I shall make my modal view
   the root view of another window and display that window.

What I am trying to achieve is very similar to showing UIAlertView, only in my case, I want my view to be fully customizable.

Thanks,